# Putting pseudocode in a framed box

Tags: framed, pseudocode

I added some pseudocode to my document in this style:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
\State $i\gets 0$
\Else
\If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets i+k$
\EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
```

I want my pseudocode to appear in a box, i.e. framed.

I tried

```
\framebox{ 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] ...     
    \end{algorithmic} 
}
```

but that gave me tons of errors and didn't divide the code on multiple lines.

How can I frame my pseudocode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `\varwidth` you can set an upper limit as the width of the line minus the space taken up by the box margins, but allow it to shrink if possible to the longest line of the display

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
\State $i\gets 0$
\Else
\If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets i+k$
\EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{varwidth}% 
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You only need to adjust the minipage's width to avoid overfull.

*Edit:* adding some comments from David.

```
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
\State $i\gets 0$
\Else
\If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets i+k$
\EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}% 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, that solves my issue. Which parameter instead of \linewidth has to be used in order to limit the width to the necessary amount, so that it just frames the content?

Comment: @bogus, this is a good question. Now we have to wait the experts... sorry.

Comment: Solved: \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth} where 0.5 is an arbitrary factor to scale the width

Comment: you need `\fbox{%` and `\end{minipage}%` otherwise you have a word space at start and end of a box then  use `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax` as the width to allow for the rule and padding on either side and use `\noindent\fbox` so the whole thing is flush left not indented.

Comment: that looks interesting, but as a novice I find it difficult to understand it. can you provide an example?

Comment: @bogus, I edited. You have to subtract the spaces (twice, from both sides of the box). So you subtract the width of the frame `fboxrule` and also the space inside the box around the contents `fboxsep`. Similar when you measure a room outside and inside. You have the width of the walls.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, why is necessary to use `\relax`?

Comment: It isn't necessary but if you use it anyway then you don't need to know the internals of `minipage`. the scanning of the arithmetic expression of `\dimexpr` may be stopped by many things but until it sees an unexpandable token that is not allowed there it will keep expanding ahead looking for more infix expressions. If it sees `\relax` not only does it stop looking for more of the expression it _removes_ the `\relax` as part of the expression syntax so that the `\relax` only stops the length expression and is not actually passed on to the scanner.

Comment: That's still wider than necessary for the content

Comment: @bogus yes it's full width (you might want to look at the `varwidth` package for a version of minipage that can (usually) adjust itself to the width of the content